# Unable to print the message sent from user space C application to linux kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel, c

I have developed a simple linux kernel module :

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>


ssize_t exer_open(struct inode *pinode, struct file *pfile) {

    return 0;
}

ssize_t exer_read(struct file *pfile, char __user *buffer, size_t length, loff_t *offset) {

    return 0;
}

ssize_t exer_write(struct file *pfile, const char __user *buffer, size_t length, loff_t *offset) {

    return length;
}

ssize_t exer_close(struct inode *pinode, struct file *pfile) {

    return 0;
}

struct file_operations exer_file_operations = { 
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .open = exer_open,
    .read = exer_read,
    .write = exer_write,
    .release = exer_close,
};

int exer_simple_module_init(void) {

    printk(KERN_ALERT "Inside the %s function\n", __FUNCTION__);
    register_chrdev(240, "Simple Char Drv", &exer_file_operations);
    return 0;
}

void exer_simple_module_exit(void) {

    unregister_chrdev(240, "Simple Char Drv");
}

module_init(exer_simple_module_init);
module_exit(exer_simple_module_exit);
```

I insert this module to the kernel using `insmod` command without any problem.

I want to use this module to print a message sent to it by user space program that I have developed too :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>


int main()

{

int ret, fd;
char stringToSend[] = "Hello World !";

fd = open("/dev/char_device", O_RDWR);             // Open the device with read/write access

if (fd < 0)
    {
            perror("Failed to open the device...");
            return errno;
    }

ret = write(fd, stringToSend, strlen(stringToSend)); // Send the string to the LKM

if (ret < 0)
    {
            perror("Failed to write the message to the device.");
            return errno;
    }

return 0;

}
```

When I execute the program and examin the kernel logs using `tail -f /var/log/messages` command I can see : `user.alert kernel: Inside the exer_read function` But I cant see the message " Hello World !"

I don't know what I am missing here especially I still beginner in developing modules and using it. Help me please!

Comment: Where are you expecting to see the message "Hello World !"? You are not printing it, or doing anything with it for that matter.

Comment: How can I do that ? How can I pass this message ( "Hello World!") from my user space program in order to be written in the file device of the module and be printed when I tape `tail -f /var/log/messages` or `dmesg` ?

Comment: Your string is passed to the `exer_read` function in the `buffer` parameter. Before you can do anything with it in the kernel, you will have to copy it using the `copy_from_user` function.

Comment: so I have to add `copy_from_user` function inside `exer_read` function ?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, I meant `copy_to_user` in the read function (and `copy_from_user` in the write function.) But yes, you need to call these functions to copy data between user space and the kernel. I strongly recommend to read up on these things before trying to build a driver. One good book (though a bit old already) is "Linux Device Drivers".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people who still can't find a solution for that, I have an answer.

This is the module :

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/device.h>  
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>


MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");      
MODULE_AUTHOR("Gaston");  
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A simple Linux char driver"); 
MODULE_VERSION("0.1"); 

#define MAX 256

static char message[MAX] ="";           ///< Memory for the string that is passed from userspace


ssize_t exer_open(struct inode *pinode, struct file *pfile) {

    printk(KERN_INFO "Device has been opened\n");
    return 0;
}


ssize_t exer_read(struct file *pfile, char __user *buffer, size_t length, loff_t *offset) {

    return 0;
}


ssize_t exer_write(struct file *pfile, const char __user *buffer, size_t length, loff_t *offset) {
    if (length > MAX)
        return -EINVAL;

    if (copy_from_user(message, buffer, length) != 0)
        return -EFAULT;

    printk(KERN_INFO "Received %s characters from the user\n", message);
    return 0;

}   


ssize_t exer_close(struct inode *pinode, struct file *pfile) {

    printk(KERN_INFO "Device successfully closed\n");
    return 0;
}


struct file_operations exer_file_operations = { 
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .open = exer_open,
    .read = exer_read,
    .write = exer_write,
    .release = exer_close,
};


int exer_simple_module_init(void) {

    printk(KERN_INFO "Initializing the LKM\n");
    register_chrdev(240, "Simple Char Drv", &exer_file_operations);
    return 0;
}


void exer_simple_module_exit(void) {

    unregister_chrdev(240, "Simple Char Drv");
}

module_init(exer_simple_module_init);
module_exit(exer_simple_module_exit);
```

Ans this is the application :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>


#define BUFFER_LENGTH 256 

int main()

{

int ret, fd;
char stringToSend[BUFFER_LENGTH];


fd = open("/dev/char_device", O_RDWR);             // Open the device with read/write access

if (fd < 0)
    {
            perror("Failed to open the device...");
            return errno;
    }


printf("Type in a short string to send to the kernel module:\n");

scanf("%s", stringToSend);                // Read in a string (with spaces)

printf("Writing message to the device [%s].\n", stringToSend);

ret = write(fd, stringToSend, strlen(stringToSend)); // Send the string to the LKM

if (ret < 0)
    {
            perror("Failed to write the message to the device.");
            return errno;
    }

return 0;

}
```

You will see that this will work fine.